# re.findall not placing all information in a list

Tags: python, regex

I have information separated by semi-colon and I'm trying to place it all in a list:

```
txt = Alert Level: 3; Rule: 5502 - Login session closed.; Location: mycomputer->/var/log/secure;Jul  1 14:22:25 MYCOMPUTER sshd[6470]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
```

When I use this expression:

```
result = re.findall('.*?;', txt)
```

I get back:

```
result = [' Alert Level: 3;', ' Rule: 5502 - Login session closed.;', ' Location: MYCOMPUTER->/var/log/secure;']
```

I'm missing the last bit of information after the last semi-colon and I'm not sure how to have it grab that and place it in the list as well. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you not use `split` instead?

```
result = txt.split(";")
```

Otherwise, if you absolutely want regex, I would use:

```
result = re.findall('[^;]+', str)
```

Comment: ...and you could tidy it up with `result = [t.strip() for t in txt.split(";")]`

Comment: Thank you both, apparently I was trying to make it harder on myself then it needed to be. Splitting it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.*?(;|$)
```

`$` being the typical symbol for the end of the line, so `(;|$)` would be either a ';' or end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if your problem is only this, you would be better of using Python's split than regexps -

But as far as your expression is concerned, it have to search by either ";" or line-ending. Unfortunately, line ending is a represetned by the `$` special character that cannot be found with simple `[ ]` frouping - 
but it can be matched by a sub-regular expression using non-capturing parentheses ( `(?:)`) and "or" ( `|`) such as this one:`re.findall(r".*?(?:;|$)", txt)`

Comment: Thank you, I went with splitting it to make it a little more simplistic but knowing how to handle it in regex is helpful.